# How to correctly update SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I know how to read write data to an android SQL database, but i ran over a problem when i am trying to append data. When i do that it only appends Last record.

For data update i am using `

```
ContentValues updateKoment = new ContentValues();
            updateKoment.put("comment", text.getText().toString());
             db.update("MyTab",updateKoment, "PhoneNr='"+newn+"'AND Name='"+contact+"'AND comment='"+previuscom+"' AND Answered='"+Yn+"'",null);
```

It would be nice if you could help me and point me in the right direction.

Comment: There's not enough context to know what's wrong (are you looping? what do you do with the `updateKoment`? Etc.), post some more of your code.

Comment: updateKoment is meant to replace my previous with new one and save it to database.

Comment: What does "only appends last record" mean?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you are trying to accomplish? It seems like you could make your life a lot easier if you had some sort of unique identifier for each row in your table, then perhaps you wouldn't need to try and match 4 requirements for every update. Then again, maybe this all makes sense, but it's hard to figure out without context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're trying to add a new comment to the end of any existing comments? If that is the case, you should probably re-design your database where you add (that is, `insert`) any new comments to a separate table. All comments are then linked to whatever other items you want to with a common key (the `post_id` column in the below example).

You could for example have this table setup in your database:

```
Table Posts:
post_id  title  description
1        'Hey'  'Description'
2        'Ho'   'Another Description'


Table Comments:
comment_id  post_id  comment
1           1        'Nice Salute'
2           1        'Yeah really nice'
3           2        'Ho Ho Ho'
```

As of your current code snippet the last comment will always replace any existing comments, that is, adding the `'Yeah really nice'` comment would replace the `'Nice salute'` comment.

(I don't believe I'm suggesting what I am about to suggest :)

You could also read any existing comments from your database and concatenate the new comment to the result:

```
String columns = { "comment" };
String constraint = "PhoneNr=? AND Name=? AND comment=? AND Answered=?";
String args[] = { newn, contact, previuscom, Yn };

Cursor cursor = db.query("MyTab", columns , constraint, args, null, null, null);
String comments = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("comment"));
comments += text.getText().toString();
```

And then update the same row with your new comments string:

```
ContentValues updateKoment = new ContentValues();
updateKoment.put("comment", comments);
db.update("MyTab", updateKoment, constraint, args);
```

But as of my personal opinion this is a butt-ugly solution and the database architect within me would strongly discourage you implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is `insert`
[android SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

```
insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's trying to do, he's got all those conditions in the WHERE section...

Comment: @Barak You are probably right.. thats just how it sounds like (if you ignore the code snippet)